# Itemize bullets without itemization?

Tags: beamer, itemize

How can I produce bullets like

[image]

as they are used in `beamer` with `itemize` environments? I want to use them in the text not just for itemizations. Note: I would like the bullets not just to look more or less like the `beamer` `itemize` bullets but they should look identical in colour, shape, and size!

Comment: which theme are you using to get that style of bullet? `\labelitemi` should give you the commands used for a first level itemize.

Comment: Just the standard theme together with `\usepackage{beamerthemeshadow}` ... `\labelitemi` gives error *undefined control sequence* !?!

Comment: sorry beamer doesn't follow the standard latex usage here, see the code in my answer which will use whichever bullet the beamer theme is using.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\mysphere{%
  \parbox[t]{10pt}{\raisebox{0.2pt}{\beamer@usesphere{item projected}{bigsphere}}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\mysphere test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 13):

This (`beamer`-specific) solution works as well, and without `@` :

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[ball] % Probably already provided by your theme

This is the bullet : \usebeamertemplate{itemize item}{}.

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: Bullet]

Comment: Yes, it's already provided by my theme!

Answer (score 8):

It seems beamer doesn't define `\labelitemi` but

```
 \csname @itemlabel\endcsname
```

works.

Comment: Yep! Thanks. Could you briely explain the code?

Comment: Beamer uses `\@itemlabel` to make the label and then each theme defines that do whatever kind of marker it wants. the `csname` usage just means you don't need `@` to be a letter, better to go `\makeatletter\def\mybullet{\@itemlabel}\makeatother` in the preamble so you can use `\mybullet` without worrying about `@`.

Comment: Thx, but still a problem. Try this: `\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{beamerthemeshadow}
\usepackage{xspace}
\newcommand{\beamerbullet}{\makeatletter\def\mybullet{\@itemlabel}\makeatother\xspace}
\begin{document}
  \beamerbullet abc\\  
  \beamerbullet cde
\end{document}` It won't produce any bullets!?

Comment: @lpdbw Don't use `\makeat*` inside of `\newcommand`. Wrap it around: `\makeatletter\newcommand*\beamerbullet{\@itemlabel}\makeatother`.