# Getting the theme's itemize bullet in beamer?

Tags: beamer, itemize

I was wondering if there is a way to get the `itemize` bullet symbol defined by the theme in `beamer`.  More precisely, I'd like to manually place the bullet symbol somewhere in the text.

One option is to look in the style file of the theme and place the appropriate mark manually (e.x. in `default` theme the bullet is a `$\blacktriangleright$` and I can place the same symbol whenever I want -- I also have to take care of the color and size, ...) but in this case if I want to change the theme it will be a mess!

I believe there must be a better way to do this ...

Thanks,

Comment: Is this what you want? http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/84166/1952

Comment: @Ignasi yes but none of the answers there seem to work ...

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 4):

You can use the appropriate `template`, `font`, and color`, to define a command; in this way you assure that your definition will honour the settings of the selected theme:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\newcommand\Mitemitem{%
  \begingroup
  \leavevmode
  \usebeamerfont*{itemize item}%
  \usebeamercolor[fg]{itemize item}%
  \usebeamertemplate**{itemize item}%
  \endgroup
}
\newcommand\Mitemsubitem{%
  \begingroup
  \leavevmode
  \usebeamerfont*{itemize subitem}%
  \usebeamercolor[fg]{itemize subitem}%
  \usebeamertemplate**{itemize subitem}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\Mitemitem\ AAA

\Mitemsubitem\ AAA
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The same code, but with the `default` theme gives

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot Gonzalo! It works.

The only issue is that in the second level of `itemize' (nested itemize) I get a bigger bullet (i.e. that of the first level).  Could you please help me fix this?

Comment: @ManiBastaniParizi Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

In case somebody is interested to see how that works for enumerations, i.e., numbered lists, here's the code, adapted from `Gonzalo Medina`.

```
\newcounter{copyOfCurrentNumber}
\newcommand{\EnumItem}[1] {%
  \begingroup
  \setcounter{copyOfCurrentNumber}{\theenumi}
  \setcounter{enumi}{#1}
  \leavevmode
  \usebeamerfont*{enumerate item}%
  \usebeamercolor[fg]{enumerate item}%
  \usebeamertemplate**{enumerate item}%
  \setcounter{enumi}{\thecopyOfCurrentNumber}
  \endgroup
}
```

Now what that code does in addition to replacing itemize by enumerate is to "save" the current enumeration number. So the command `\EnumItem` receives an argument which equals the number that is supposed to be printed (in the style of the enumerate list of course). But by *setting* the enumeration number to that of the argument (i.e., the printed number) we change the current enumerate number as a side effect. That is a problem if we are currently within such an enumerate. Thus the code saves the current number in a new variable, and copies it back once the job is done.

Below is the example code plus is visualization.

```
\begin{frame}[t]{Example}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item First list entry.
    \item This is label 5: \EnumItem{5} (although we don't have that list entry).
    \item Third entry. Still starts with 3, not with 6! Phew! 
  \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
```

[image]