# Beamer: How to get value behind \setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{} and related?

Tags: beamer, itemize

I know that I can change the itemize symbol in a LaTeX Beamer presentation with `\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}{\symbol}`. I use a corporate template which defines the symbol that way. Now I want to use the same symbol for something else in the presentation.

But how can I get the current value back? Is there something like `\thebeameritemizeditem` to return `\symbol`?

What I've tried so far:

- When I use `\meaning\labelitemi` which is defined in `article.cls` as mentioned in [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42805/what-are-original-itemize-bullet-definitions) I get the output `undefined`.
- When I try `\csname@itemlabel\endcsname` as proposed in [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84166/itemize-bullets-without-itemization) I just get a blank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, reading until the end sometimes helps. `\usebeamertemplate{itemize item}{}` also from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84166/itemize-bullets-without-itemization) worked.